# Default.png not showing on iPad device, but showing on iPad simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, splash-screen

It's driving me crazy. I've been searching for solution on the web for hours but nothing helps. I have an universal app, cocos2d game. iPhone launch images are showing perfectly but not iPad ones. The iPad files are:

```
 Default-Landscape~ipad.png
 Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png
 Default-Portrait~ipad.png
 Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png
```

If i launch the app in the simulator it works just fine, the correct image is displayed. But when i do that on a real iPad weird things start to happen. It takes iPhone image instead of iPad one. I presume so cause the image is stretched and turned upside down. If i completely remove iPhone images from the project it just shows nothing, black screen only. A real device ignores the files listed above. Anybody, please, suggest a solution

Comment: Check your `info.plist` has the same cases then you files. The iOS device is case sensitive.

Comment: press Command + Shift + K on Xcode to clean project, after that delete app on iPad, connect iPad to computer and rebuild app

Comment: @rckoenes but i didn't put filenames into info.plist cause they are default. and for iPhone it works all right. However i just put this <key>UILaunchImageFile~ipad</key>
    <string>Default-Landscape~ipad.png</string> into plist and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that despite .png extension files were jpg really. After re-saving these files as png in Photoshop everything eventually started to work

Answer (score 0):

i think your image name is case insensitive.just try to add theimage with proper name or else check the image.Another way is right click xcodeproject file in your finder project location.and delete the xcuserdata content.And run the project again.